# AddForce по определённой части объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как мне задать центр тяжести объекту и присваивать AddForce к определённой его части?
http://screenshot.su/img/6c/0e/27/6c0e27e6c3ae355f99df543971d5fe40.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решен.

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().centerOfMass;
```